# software to switch easily between English and Japanese in windows 7

Tags: language

a user of mine had a button on her computer (XP) that makes it jump from English to Japanese and back again, she wants to find/install a similar program for windows 7. Has anybody ever heard of a similar program? I'm not having much luck with google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about switching between English and Japanese keyboard input, you should be able to just hit <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. This is configurable from the language bar settings (under the 'Advanced Key Settings' tab).